# Multithreading in java

Tags: java, applet

I want to use 4 threads in my applet and used Runnable interface wants to move all the threads around required position.

When in my applet, clouds image walks from o to 750 at y axis and the helicopter starts walking when clouds comes at 150 in y axis and helicopter walks upto it reaches to the 350 and then this thread stops.
And then when my helicopter reaches to the 200 then a man image comes out and walks to the x axis, it will stop when it has walked 5 to 10 milliseconds.

following is my code:

```
import java.applet.* ;

package com.pack;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class HelicopterScene extends Applet {
    Image a, b, c;
    int i, j, h, p;

    public void init() {
        i = 20;
        j = 750;
        h = 0;
        a = getImage(getCodeBase(), "HelicopterAttack.jpg");
        b = getImage(getCodeBase(), "pppp.png");
        c = getImage(getCodeBase(), "helicopter1.png");
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        showStatus(" Helicopter Scene Applet is started.....");
        g.drawImage(a, 0, 0, this);
        if (i <= 750 && j >= 20) {
            if (i >= 150) {
                g.drawImage(c, h, 255, 150, 35, this);
                h++;
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException w) {
                }
            }

            g.drawImage(b, j, 120, 90, 70, this);
            g.drawImage(b, i, 180, 120, 70, this);
            i++;
            j--;
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
                if (i == 750 && j == 20) {
                    p = h;
                    g.drawImage(c, p, 255, 150, 35, this);
                    h++;
                    repaint();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    } catch (InterruptedException w) {
                    }
                    i = 20;
                    j = 750;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IF that's a homework please add a appropriate tag to the question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you never want to sleep on the UI thread.  Second, you never want to paint *off* the UI thread.  You should investigate SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

Comment: please can you tell me how?
Because I m new to java concepts so i will be appreciated if you help me...
And Thanks for reply...

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29